# React node js not work properly not created my app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have installed  node.js  but it is not  work properly. bot create react app ...

[image]

need to help me in node js that is able  to create react app if it will be helped me I will be thankful.

Comment: as you can see in the output there is log file you may read. most probably the env variable of npm is not set properly.

Answer (score 0):

First, verify if the node is installed or not in your system :

node -v

If a node exists then try the command

npm -v

If both commands give the output, That means the node is properly installed into your system, and The error clearly stated that it is not able to find the npm, So The issue could be with your system too.

So try this step:

1. Uninstall the node from your system
2. Restart system
3. Install the node again into the system and then restart the system again
4. Try now if it helps.

Hope it helps!